# how to make a custom html element execute after being appended to element

Tags: javascript, html

To preface, say that we have a custom element that looks just like the one from this Autonomous custom element section from here: [example code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define#Autonomous_custom_element)

and after the page loads you wish to create a new custom element by doing something like this:

```js
    var exampleElement = document.createElement("popup-info"); //creates element
    var exampleElementImg = document.createAttribute("img"); //does not get executed until the parser has put other dom in from the custom element
    exampleElementImg.value = "img/alt.png";
    exampleElement.setAttributeNode(exampleElementImg);
    var exampleElementText = document.createAttribute("text");
    exampleElementText.value = "Hello World!";
    exampleElement.setAttributeNode(exampleElementText);
    //append exampleElement somewhere to the document
```

normally this would be fine but immediately when `createElement()` gets executed it starts appending the extra DOM immediately, but it does not wait for `createAttribute()`

I was wondering if there would be a way to get this to create the attributes before the element get parsed without using something like timeout in the constructor.

Comment: [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) creates a parentless element, it's not appended to the DOM before you explicitly do that with a specific method. Also, JavaScript is not paused when the DOM is updated, all the script is always finished before any updates to the DOM is done, unless you're forcing re-calculation.

Comment: Since it looks like the object is being appended in the Autonomous function, have you tried adding a new function in that class called something like `create` and in that function is where everything gets appended to wrapper and the shadow dom? That way after you create the element with createElement and do everything, you would then just call `exampleElement.create();`

Comment: @Teemu I do not believe that any recalculation is being done because it is what I put in my question pretty much exactly except for a few extra attributes will be added. I only noticed this behavior when I was trying to get an attribute from the constructor and it was returning null which I presume means that it could not find the attribute.

Comment: @imvain2 it looks like your solution worked, but could you give an answer to the question so I can give you the credit for doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that is a class you can create a separate function within that class like ‘create’ and within that function is where you have all of the appending functions that append the objects to the shadow dom and wrapper.

Then call it like below after you have added the attributes and so on.

‘exampleElement.create();’